python aiogram 3.x | Как разнести данные по кнопкам для telegram?
У меня есть код, который запрашивает данные с сайта в виде текстовых значений (всего 8 значений). Как сделать, чтобы получилось 1 кнопка = 1 значение (по порядку). Заранее извиняюсь за тупняк, я новичок
Данные приходят через код:
class Reg(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    name1 = State()
 
@dp.message(StateFilter(Reg.name1))
async def processing_code(message: Message,
                         state: FSMContext,
) -> None:       
    await state.update_data(name1=message.text)
    await state.set_state(None)
    data = await state.get_data()
    async with "" as api:
            await api.update_assets()
            try:
                response = await api.fetch_***(data['name1'])
            except .errors.PlayerDoesNotExistError:
                return message.answer("")
            except KeyError:
                return message.answer("")
            except .errors.GameMaintenanceError:
                return message.answer("")
            except ValueError:
                return message.answer("")
                
            for character in response.characters:
            markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
            [InlineKeyboardButton(text='аыпыке', callback_data='character1'), InlineKeyboardButton(text='кыпавпа', callback_data='character2')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton(text='текст', callback_data='character3'), InlineKeyboardButton(text='текст12', callback_data='character4')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton(text='текс3434т', callback_data='character5'), InlineKeyboardButton(text='текст232', callback_data='character6')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton(text='теdft434т', callback_data='character7'), InlineKeyboardButton(text='тек3432', callback_data='character8')]],
            resize_keyboard=True,
            one_time_keyboard=True
            )
                return message.answer("Выберите персонажа", reply_markup=markup)

character.name включает в себя 8 текстовых значений (имена персонажей)
Должно быть 8 кнопок соответствующих имени персонажа

У вас правильная идея, использовать цикл for. Просто вы для каждого персонажа генерируете клавиатуру целиком (ещё похоже на ошибку отступа).
Вам нужна конструкция примерно такая
buttons = []
for character in response.characters:
    buttons.append(InlineKeyboardButton(text=character.name, callback_data=character.num))

markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=buttons, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)

Главное, отправлять сообщение и формировать клавиатуру вне цикла

Не робит. Надо достать именно из character.name текст. Т.е. character.name включает в себя 8 элементов

@Torrtozzo опишите структуру в вопросе, гадать у меня не очень получается)
В таком случае, лучше пройти циклом по character.name

Смотрите, функция запрашивает данные с сайта. С сайта приходят данные. Из кусочка данных я беру characters, которое содержит всю информацию о персонажах того или иного игрока, затем из этой информации я беру characters.name, которое содержит только имена персонажей.  Имена располагаются в порядке 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8, мне нужно их всех по порядку вытащить и поставить для каждой кнопки 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8. Я извиняюсь за свои кривые изъяснения, я менее чем 2 недели назад начал изучать питон, созданием ботов занимаюсь менее недели (совсем newbie, за многое не шарю)

структуру приложите к вопросу. Прямо вот как вы запрос сделали и получили что-то. Вот это "что-то" к вопросу приложите

Я использую wrapper, чтобы взаимодействовать с API нужного сайта. Структуру самого враппера я еще изучаю. Если поможет понять контекст, то при print(character.name) в терминал по порядку в столбик выводятся имена персонажей. Мне вот надо как-то пока они выводятся по одному их пихать в кнопки, после чего вывести 8 кнопок
может быть я делаю что-то вообще не то

Пока что получается запихать в кнопки первый текст из character.name, второй и последующие игнорируются

Я всё ещё не могу вам помочь, так как не понимаю, как у вас структурированы данные в character.name. Если у вас там список, то нужно по нему итерироваться, если строка, то получить из неё список (.split) и итерироваться. Пока, из ваших объяснений, я не особо понял что у вас там. А возможно, что ошибка в том, что у вас некорректный отступ, и return происходит В цикле, завершая его

АА, там много текста. Вроде бы там строка и в ней значения идут по порядку. Я могу отправить полный текст данных из основных данных, в которое входит characters.name. Если, конечно, захотите со мной и всем этим разбираться
