aiogram 3.x | Как подставлять ключи или значения из словаря в переменные для дальнейшей обработки
Я получаю словарь, затем из словаря достаю либо ключи либо значения. После чего хочу подставить их в кнопки или в текст. Т.е. надо не конкретно эти 1308, 1112, 1309... подставить, а любые ключи, которые приходят на их место
key_id = data.get_charter() # Делает словарь из приходящих данные
names = key_id.keys()
print(names)

Вывод
dict_keys(['1308', '1112', '1309', '1005', '1205', '1006', '1307', '1306'])

Всего 8 ключей и они всегда меняются, т.к. я запрашиваю данные о пользователе. Всегда приходят разные ключи и значения.
Я пытался сделать
key_id = data.get_charter()
            char1 = list(key_id.values())[0]
            char2 = list(key_id.values())[1]
            char3 = list(key_id.values())[2]
            char4 = list(key_id.values())[3]
            char5 = list(key_id.values())[4]
            char6 = list(key_id.values())[5]
            char7 = list(key_id.values())[6]
            char8 = list(key_id.values())[7]
            print(
            char1, char2, char3, char4, char5, char6, char7, char8)

Выводит всё правильно как мне надо, но в кнопки подставить не могу
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not InlineKeyboardBurtton


И в идеале еще как-то решить вопрос с тем, что если ключей приходит не 8, а 5, и выдает list index out of range

С out of range вопрос решил

Что-то я не пойму, вы уже вроде задавали этот вопрос и даже несколько раз. Зачем вы дублируете вопросы?

Опять ключи... опять "опять" повторения... Зачем? Вам ответов на те же самы вопросы не хватает? Или вы проводите стресс-тест памяти участников сообщества?

Работайте с вопросами по отдельности, не надо из них "лепить" "новый". Если потеряли: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1596142 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1596041
